# Boost solr fields when the deafult field is multifield

Tags: boost, solr

I am using solr 7.5

The default field for search is a multifield which contains 4 fields for example `ProductNo, ProductDescription, ProductCode and ProductName`. When I search for anything I get results if the query matches from that multifield.

Now I want to increase the score of a document by boosting `ProductCode and ProductDescription`.

So when I search for `123` which is actually a `ProductCode` I should see the documents in below order. Similar the case with ProductDescription.

```
ProductCode: 123
ProductCode: 12345
ProductCode: 0001234
```

Can we boost individual fields when the default filed is a multifield?

EDIT:

I am searching on a field search_general_multifiled which contains 6 other fields.

Ex:

```
search_general_multifield [
"This is Product Name",
"This is Product Title",
"123",
"Product Description"
]
```

The config of request handler is as follows:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <int name="rows">10</int>
    <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
    <str>spellcheck</str>
    <str>elevator</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/select?defType=edismax&q=2210&df=search_general_multifield&qf=productNo^10.0

I tried above query to boost only productNo field but it does not work. The results were as below

```
Product1: 22210
Product2: 22105
Product3: 22106
```

But I am expecting `22105, 22106 and 22210 or 22106, 22105 and 22210`

Somehow the score of the 22210 is always higher than the other two. Below was the way how score of the docs were calculated.

"\n12.612339 = weight(search_general_multifield:2210 in 81105) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n 12.612339 = score(doc=81105,freq=5.0 = termFreq=5.0\n), product of:\n 6.1082788 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n 603.0 = docFreq\n 271311.0 = docCount\n 2.0647943 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n 5.0 = termFreq=5.0\n 1.2 = parameter k1\n 0.75 = parameter b\n 525.41583 = avgFieldLength\n 16.0 = fieldLength\n"

"\n12.600186 = weight(search_general_multifield:2210 in 84746) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n 12.600186 = score(doc=84746,freq=5.0 = termFreq=5.0\n), product of:\n 6.1082788 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n 603.0 = docFreq\n 271311.0 = docCount\n 2.0628047 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n 5.0 = termFreq=5.0\n 1.2 = parameter k1\n 0.75 = parameter b\n 525.41583 = avgFieldLength\n 19.0 = fieldLength\n"

"\n12.600186 = weight(search_general_multifield:2210 in 85128) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n 12.600186 = score(doc=85128,freq=5.0 = termFreq=5.0\n), product of:\n 6.1082788 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n 603.0 = docFreq\n 271311.0 = docCount\n 2.0628047 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n 5.0 = termFreq=5.0\n 1.2 = parameter k1\n 0.75 = parameter b\n 525.41583 = avgFieldLength\n 19.0 = fieldLength\n"

Comment: I'm not sure what the field being multivalued should change. A boost is applied regardless based on whether a hit is present or not. Your requirement seems to be that you want to do an ngram match, so you'll need proper processing for the field you want to use for boosting (which can be an fifth field) to generate the required tokens. What the default field is defined as isn't relevant for how the boost will be applied. If you have tried something that has failed, include that in your question with appropriate test documents.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, Yes I am using ngram search for that. And I want to increase the score of documents by boosting few fields, but I don't see any results.

Comment: You'll have to show what you've tried and compare the output when adding `debug=all` to your query string (so you can see exactly how the score is calculated). It's impossible to say anything useful unless you provide proper details about what you're doing now and what you expected to happen.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, I edited my post. Can you please check now? Also I used edismax to boost the fields, but its not working.

Comment: What is the type of the `productNo` field? From your examples there is no reason why `2210` should match any of the product numbers stored there. I also suggest using `bq` and `boost` to perform boosting.

Comment: The type of all the fields are String... and I am using ngram filter factory so 2210 will match the products I mentioned. Use bq means??? something like this `http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/select?defType=edismax&q=2210&df=search_general_multifield&bq=productNo:2210^10.0`

Comment: If the fields are of type string, no processing will happen. And since you don't have an exact match, no boosting will happen for those fields in that case. While your search field might be a textfield with an ngram filter attached, if your boosting field is a string field, `2210` will not match anything.

Comment: What if I change the fields type to text? will that work?

Comment: If you expect 2210 to give hits, you'll have to have a field type with an ngram analyzer (edgengram if you only want to boost those from the front, or ngram if you want to boost anything containing), yes.

Comment: I changed the filed types with ngram analyzer. Now all the three products having the same score. But I want to show the products in below order because I am searching with 2210. 
`Product2: 22105
Product3: 22106
Product1: 22210`  I don't understand why those are having the same score. Is it because of Ngram analyzer? I cannot even change the score by boosting the productNo, because all scores gets multiplied by 10 and the score will be same again.

Comment: Yes, the boost will apply to all the fields that match tokens. Here's the deal - you'll have to formulate _why_ it should be ordered in that way, and then have fields that reflect matches that allows you to apply boosts depending on which match occurs. Why should 22105 be boosted more than 22106 when the query is 2210? For the third case I assume you really want an EdgeNGramFilter to boost prefix matches instead of boosting any match inside the token.